# Avoid page brake inside a row with rowspan with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate a pdf which contains a table and I am getting a page break inside of a row this is what don't want to occur.
[image: This is where the table breaks between pages]

Here is my html code and css code, I have tried page-break-avoids, etc but still no solution.
I am debating if this is a wkhtmltopdf error or something in my css code

```css
thead {
    display: table-row-group;
}
tr.test {
    page-break-before: avoid;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
table {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
table td {
    word-break: break-all;
}

table,tr, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>4</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>5</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>4</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>5</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>4</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>5</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>4</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>5</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>4</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>5</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>3</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>4</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>5</td><td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    
  
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: i would have tried `page-break-before: always;` , did you ?

Comment: Yep already tried